# Rewrite functions in pywb without code source changing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new in python development and I'm using PYWB library for replaying web archives (warc files).

I would like to modify a function in `pywb/warcserver/index` but without modifying the code source.

The idea is to modify some features while keeping the original code source. It will be useful to update the code source without loosing changes.

How can this be possible in pywb with python.

The function to rewrite in the `indexsource.py` file is `load_index`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`load_index` is a method of the `FileIndexSource` class. You can modify the method on an instance level without having to change the source code of the library. For example:

```
from pywb.utils.binsearch import iter_range
from pywb.utils.wbexception import NotFoundException
from pywb.warcserver.index.cdxobject import CDXObject
from pywb.utils.format import res_template

def modified_load_index(self, params):

    filename = res_template(self.filename_template, params)

    try:
        fh = open(filename, 'rb')
    except IOError:
        raise NotFoundException(filename)

    def do_load(fh):
        with fh:
            gen = iter_range(fh, params['key'], params['end_key'])
            for line in gen:
                yield CDXObject(line)

    # (... some modification on this method)
    return do_load(fh)

# Change the "load_index" method on the instance of FileIndexSource
my_file_index_source.load_index = modified_load_index
```

For then on, every time the method `load_index` is called on `my_file_index_source`, it will be the modified method that will run.

Another option would be to make a new class which inherits from `FileIndexSource` and overwrites the `load_index` method.

Comment: Thanks for reply, this script will be in which folder (in wich file)?, and how it can be called befor the original function? How can I tell to the pywb to call my_file_index_source instead of file_index_source?  Thanks

Comment: You are running it as `wayback [...]` ?

Comment: No @Jundiaius, I'm ruuning it with uwsgi uwsgi.ini The uwsgi.ini file is on github, it contains wsgi = pywb.apps.wayback